# Android DEX's 64k limit and diverse hacks without a simple and clear solution

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

I have more than 64K functions on my Android application and I want compile it and it's not possible in a 'normal' way. Searching over the network I've found some esotheric hacks to fragment the dex file and achieve compile the program.

Recently google has released the support for multidex and I expected that finally I can generate the program without tricks and hacks. But seems that I want a miracle o something similar. I've created my application that extends a MultiDexApplication that seems the solution to do this but I don't found the form to say to Eclipse that fragments the dex file properly. Somebody knows how to resolve this problem.
I'm using Eclipse with no Maven and no Gradle.

Thanks

**Edit 10/27/2014** : I fixed the problem using Eclipse + Android Maven Plugin. People has fixed the problem using Android Studio + Gradle. I expect that in the future this problem will be fixed using only Eclipse because do a make maven install and maven deploy every time is too slow.

Comment: As far as I know, you still have to use `sorcery and evocations`.

Comment: asking similar questions over and over again will not help

Comment: I'm trying to explain better the problem, asking will not help if I don't get an answer positive or negative.

Comment: Do you _need_ all of those methods or are they included from the support libraries? Remove them using proguard if they're not needed.

Comment: I need them is a big project